# Can anyone help me with this Parsing Error in my PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell, parsing-error

I have a PowerShell function where I'm getting a strange parsing error (it won't compile, both PowerGUI (the editor I use), and PowerShell (when I try to Import-Module)), give me a Parsing error.

Here's a link to pastebin with my code: [My Function @ Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xca3inJ3)

Here's a link to a picture showing the parsing-error-message: [Error message @ Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbiAB.jpg)

Anyone familiar with this parsing error? I tried deleting the `Write-Verbose`statements it complained about, but that didn't help any, it just jumped to the next one, even if it was inside a completely different codeblock. (E.G. `Process{...}` vs `End{...}`).

Comment: Please post your code here.. I cant get to pastebin from work

Comment: please DON'T post your entire code at pastebin. Just give us the error message and the snippet which causes the error.

Comment: @BugFinder: That's strange, I just tested it now and the servers are not down. It's the same technologies as StackOverflow use, so if you can use this site, you should be able to view Pastebin.

Comment: @Matten: I did give you the error message, the second link, picture at Imgur. And if you had checked it, you'd also see I left the Line Numbers visible, so you can then go to PasteBin and just scroll down at your leisure, I struggle to see the difficulty in understanding the concept on how to accomplish this =/
If you think the picture is too small, then just click it. It's Imgurs own formatting that zooms out on the pic.

Comment: @x10an14 you make the assumption my anal employer hasnt blocked the site on all the proxy servers... Also, it has always been preferred that people post the actual code and stuff here so its easy for anyone to get to

Comment: @x10an14 Imgur isn't available at my workplace.

Comment: Oh, ok, I was afraid you guys would get offended if I just posted big walls of text which I've experienced happening other places on the `Net, but if that's not the case, I'll start doing that when I use StackOverflow =) (This is my second question on site, I hope you can forgive my newbishness^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a backtick before on the quote before 'Any Errors' on line 161:

```
Write-Error "`"Could not connect to remote computer $server!`"`n`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t      "Any errors on line 109 relates to this fact.`""
```

Should be:

```
Write-Error "`"Could not connect to remote computer $server!`"`n`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t      `"Any errors on line 109 relates to this fact.`""
```

That caused some mismatched quotes which then caused the last quote in your script, i.e. the one at the end of "Returning Hashtable..." on line 247, to throw an error.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you, newbish of me! =)
I was not aware that the Debug/Verbose/Error -Write lines were counted as one big one, but I was starting to suspect it. Hopefully you can have some use of the function yourself (I know I will at home, not just at work where I wrote it for)!